# priority_queue operator < implementation trouble

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, priority-queue

I have multiple events of different types that I need to push into a priority queue and make sure they are sorted by the event time.

```
struct Event {
    double event_time;
    int type;
};
```

I use a class EventCompare like so:

```
class EventCompare {
public:
    bool operator()(Event &a, Event &b) {
        return a.event_time > b.event_time;
    }
};
```

and initialize the priority queue:

```
priority_queue<Event, vector<Event>, EventCompare> event_scheduler;
```

When I push Events into the priority queue, they are still not sorted. Is there something wrong with my implementation?

I generate my Events in such a way:

```
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
while(action_time < 100) {
    u = (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
    action_time += -log(u)/25;
    Event e = {action_time, 0};
    event_scheduler.push(e);
}
```

I then do another similar loop but resetting the rand seed, setting action_time back to 0, and for an event with type 1, the event with type 1 does not get placed in order of event_time.

Comment: what do you means not sorted? how do you know it?

Comment: I mean when I start popping from the head of the queue, the values do not come out from lowest to highest.

Comment: You should take the arguments by `const` reference: `bool operator()( const Event& a, const Event& b );`

Comment: I apologize John. I was indeed looking at only local values as I was debugging. I totally forgot the priority queue uses a heap and only when you pop the head does the next value bubble to the top.

Answer (score 1):

If you're intending for the oldest events (event_time lowest) to be at top of the queue, you need to reverse your custom compare. By default std::priority_queue puts the greatest at the top:

```
class EventCompare {
public:
    bool operator()(Event &a, Event &b) {
        return a.event_time > b.event_time;
    }
};
```

This works fine for me. Example at [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d73221e6e8fa8e54)

Comment: I reversed my comparison and added to my question on how I generate my events.

Comment: See modified coliru using your way of generating the events: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d80a0fae07062703